# Method chainning for join table with pagination on CI 3

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, chaining

I create a core class named MY_Model that extends CI_Model. In this class, I create a method chaining to get all record with pagination like this :

```
// Take record with paging.
public function get_all_paged()
{
    // get argument that passed
    $args = func_get_args();

    // get_all_paged($offset)
    if (count($args) < 2) {
        $this->get_real_offset($args[0]);
        $this->db->limit($this->_per_page, $this->_offset);
    }

    // get_all_paged(array('status' => '1'), $offset)
    else {
        $this->get_real_offset($args[1]);
        $this->db->where($args[0])->limit($this->_per_page, $this->_offset);
    }

    // return all record
    return $this->db->get($this->_tabel)->result();
}
```

So , I just used like this on my controller,
**for example**

```
public function index($offset = NULL) {
    $karyawan = $this->karyawan->get_all_paged($offset); //get all

}
```

I am realy confuse to get all record using join, I know join in CI like this :

```
public function get_all_karyawan() {


    $this->db->select('tb_1 , tb_2');
    $this->db->from('tb_1');
    $this->db->join('tb_2', "where");
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->result();
}
```

How to make it into chain in MY_Model?

Any help it so appreciated ...

Answer (score 1):

The good thing in query builder, you can chain your `db` methods, till `get()`. So you can define, selects, where queries, limits in different ways.

For example:

```
public function category($category)
{
    $this->db->where('category_id', $category);
    return $this;
}

public function get_posts()
{
    return $this->db->get('posts')->result();
}
```

And you can get all posts:

`$this->model->get_posts();`

Or by category:

`$this->model->category(2)->get_posts();`

So upon this, in your model:

```
public function get_all_karyawan() {
    $this->db->select('tb_1 , tb_2');
    $this->db->join('tb_1', "where");
    // Here you make able to chain the method with this
    return $this;
}
```

In your controller:

```
public function index($offset = NULL) {
    $karyawan = $this->karyawan->get_all_karyawan()->get_all_paged($offset);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the good explanation, but it gives me error like this Error Number: 1066

Not unique table/alias: 'tb_karyawan'

Comment: Sorry, but i just explain the chaining, that was your quesiton. You have to change this `$this->db->join('tb_1', "where")`, it isn't correct, because you are joining the table to itself. And a typo is also incorrect. Read more about joins here: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html

Comment: Thanks, I read again the doc, if join, remove this->db->from(), that's the problem. Thanks again.